# How to calculate Dose-Length Product (DLP) value?

Tags: dicom

I'm looking for a DICOM Tag for Dose-Length Product (DLP) Value. If there is no such a tag, how to calculate it based on other tags?

Maybe it is a calculation between **(0018,1302) Scan Length** and **(0018,0050) Slice Thinkness** and some others but I am not sure.

DLP = Dose-Length Product [mGy x cm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a standard DICOM tag for DLP. I know it exists as a value in RDSR (Radiation Dose Structured Reports.) You could, however, calculate DLP from CTDIvol and Scan Length, assuming that you have both of those available in the header.

DLP = CTDIvol * ScanLength

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3473864/ (A method for calculating the dose length product from CT DICOM images)

Comment: But Currently I found no tag (0018,1302) scan length values in my DICOM images.

Comment: For an Axial scan, if I only repeatedly scan at the same place for 5 acquisitions without any table move, the ScanLength = 5*collimationOpening or ScanLength = collimationOpening roughly?